# Where are drafts saved in gmail android app?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gmail

I wrote an email in gmail android app and saved as draft. Then I accidentally pressed send, although I have no connection (roaming). The gmail android app annoyingly doesn't allow the message to copy anymore. Now I need to access this message. Is there a way to copy it? If not, where can I find it in the file system?

Comment: Can you see the mail in the Outbox still?

Answer (score 3):

Menu -> Go to labels -> Drafts. It's really just a label.